# Incorrect Time-Stamps In Valgrind Memory Leak Report

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am running Valgrind over a large code-base, with `"--time-stamp=yes"`

**I need to find out the ACTUAL (Relative) TIMESTAMPS at which each Memory was Allocated**

Problem: Valgrind Report contains the Time-Stamps at which Leak Summary is generated

```
Steps:

 - Run the codebase for 24 Hours with valgrind [ options
   "--tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --time-stamp=yes"]


 - Terminate the process with "kill -15" after 24 hours, Leak Summary is
   generated.


 - Time-Stamps In Valgrind Report= Time of Leak Report Generation [Not
   the Actual Time at which Memory was Allocated]
```

Is there any option thorough which I can get the ACTUAL TIMESTAMPS -- at which Leaked Memory was Allocated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, because leaks are not detected in real time - there isn't really any way to do that. Instead they are detected by scanning memory when the program finishes, to see what blocks are still reachable - anything which has been allocated but is not reachable is a leak.

Comment: Thanks, but can't valgrind provide the correct Time-Stamps for Memory Allocation atleast -- whenever leak report is generated at the end?

Comment: Yes, in principle it could record the allocation time, but it doesn't do so at the moment. Leak reports are aggregated though - each report refers to all blocks allocated at a given location so there wouldn't be a single time.